# Is it possible to create a domain with another word before the. and the rest of your URL? (Closed)

Tags: dns

so basically I'm trying to make a secondary domain that is about.wyrnz.com and I was wondering if I have to buy another domain or if it is possible to do that without buying a new domain?

Thanks everyone for replying! I've worked it out now so this is now closed!

Comment: "I've worked it out now so this is now closed!" You should then post your solution here, mark it as accepted so that 1) everyone can profit from your research and findings and 2) your question really appears to be closed (just adding "closed" in the title does not cut it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you own a second level domain (`wyrnz.com`), you can create as many sub-levels as you want. That includes third level (`xxx.wyrnz.com`), but also fourth (`yyy.xxx.wyrnz.com`) and as many levels you want.

That also depends on you host. I know that some hosts restricts the number of sub-domains you're allowed to create.

Comment: Awesome! How do I do that?

Comment: Hey, I'm just reviewing old questions I've asked and I wanted to say thanks for answering this question even though I didn't do any research into this! :)

Answer (score 1):

If www.wyrnz.com is your domain you should not have to buy another domain. In fact, you can not even buy it, you already own it. about.wyrnz.com is a subdomain of wyrnz.com.

What I did is:
Create a subfolder on the webserver, create a subdomain and point the subdomain to that folder. Every time someone types in about.wyrnz.com, the index page in the subfolder will be served to the user

Comment: How do I create a subdomain? (Sorry I'm new to this.)